# How to count when value crosses the average

Tags: mysql, count, average

I am trying to write a MySQL query that would count the number of times a value crosses a constant.  The end result is we are tying to determine the relative 'noise' of the value via the amplitude and the frequency of the value.   MIN() and MAX() provide the amplitude.  Count() gives the number of samples that fit the criteria, but it doesn't provide how stable that value is.  We are currently using MySQL 5.7 but we will be moving to MySQL 8.0 that provides the windowing features.  Something like

```
Select Count(Value) over (order by logtime ROWS 1 Proeeding <123 AND 1 Following > 123) WHERE logtime BETWEEN...;
```

Thank your for any help you can provide.

```
SELECT Count(Value) WHERE Value > 123 AND logtime BETWEEN...;

SELECT Count(Value) WHERE Value < 123 AND logtime BETWEEN...;
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results, please.

Comment: You want to count the number of adjacent rows where the first is below average and the second is above average, or vice versa. Does that description help you find the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are not available in MySQL versions before 8.0

With MySQL 5.7, we can emulate some window functions by using user-defined variables in a carefully crafted query. The MySQL Reference Manual gives explicit warning about using user-defined variables in a context like this. We are relying on behavior that is not guaranteed.

But as an example of the pattern I would use to achieve the specified result:

```
SELECT SUM(c.crossed_avg) AS count_crossed_avg
  FROM ( 
         SELECT IF( ( @prval > a.avg_ AND t.value < a.avg_ ) OR 
                    ( @prval < a.avg_ AND t.value > a.avg_ )
                ,1,0) AS crossed_avg
              , @prval := t.value AS value_
           FROM mytable t
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT 123 AS avg_ ) a
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT @prval := NULL ) i
          WHERE ...
          ORDER BY t.logtime

       ) c
```

To unpack this, focus first on the inline view query; that is, ignore the SELECT SUM() wrapper query, and run just the inline view query.

We order the rows by `logtime` so that we can process the rows in order.

We compare the value on the current row to the value from the previous row. If one is above average and the other is below average, then we return a 1, else we return 0.

Save the current value into the user-defined variable for comparing the next row. (Note: the order of operations is important; we are depending on MySQL to do that assignment *after* the evaluation of the `IF()` function.

---

The example query doesn't address the edge case when a row value is exactly equal to the average, e.g.  a sequence of values  `124.4` < `123.0` < `122.2`.  (We might want to consider changing the comparisons so that one includes the equality e.g. `<` and `>=`.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that out.